# How to test if an application and workbook are opened

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am looking for help on trying to figure out how to check if a particular workbook is opened. I have a button on my Windows form that when pressed, it will open Excel and go to a particular worksheet. However, I just ran into the problem that the user may already have that particular workbook open, so instead of creating a new instance of Excel and opening the workbook again, I want to check if that workbook is opened, if it is, then go to the selected worksheet.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnMinSummaryWorksheet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinSummaryWorksheet.Click
    'This procedure runs when the btnOpenSummaryWorksheet button is clicked. Calls the
    'Sub procedure opens the Summary Worksheet Dashboard

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Test Environment\Compensation Workbook\Compensation Workbook\bin\Debug\2011.1004.Compensation Template.xlsx")

    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    xlSheet = CType(xlBook.Sheets("SummaryWorksheet"), Worksheet)
    xlSheet.Activate()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a function that will check to see if the workbook is already open or not, like this:

```
Private Shared Function IsWorkbookAlreadyOpen(app As Excel.Application, workbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim isAlreadyOpen As Boolean = True

    Try
        app.Workbooks.get_Item(workbookName)
    Catch theException As Exception
        isAlreadyOpen = False
    End Try

    Return isAlreadyOpen
End Function
```

Then you can use it in your code like this:

```
Private Sub btnMinSummaryWorksheet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinSummaryWorksheet.Click
    'This procedure runs when the btnOpenSummaryWorksheet button is clicked. Calls the
    'Sub procedure opens the Summary Worksheet Dashboard

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim workbookName = "F:\Test Environment\Compensation Workbook\Compensation Workbook\bin\Debug\2011.1004.Compensation Template.xlsx"
    If IsWorkbookAlreadyOpen(xlApp, workbookName) Then
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.get_Item(workbookName)
    Else
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookName)
    End If

    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    xlSheet = CType(xlBook.Sheets("SummaryWorksheet"), Worksheet)
    xlSheet.Activate()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For somebody still have similar problem in 2018 :D.

Imports System.IO

```
Function FileOpenTest(ByVal WorkBookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim fs As FileStream
    FileOpenTest= False
    Try
        fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(WorkBookName)
        fs.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        FileOpenTest= True
    End Try

    Return FileOpenTest
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Collection

```
Private moExcelApplication As Excel.Application
Private moExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Private moExcelWorkBook1 As Excel.Workbook
Private moWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks
Private moActivesheet As Excel.Worksheet
Private moCurrentRange As Excel.Range



Public Function CloseExcelFile()
    Dim bprocess As Boolean
    Try
        bprocess = False
        If (Not moExcelWorkBook Is Nothing) Then
            If (Not moExcelApplication Is Nothing) Then
                moExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
                bprocess = True
            End If
        End If

        If (Not moExcelApplication Is Nothing) Then
            moExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = True
            bprocess = True

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        recordclear(moCurrentRange)
        moExcelWorkBook.Close(False)
        recordclear(moExcelWorkBook)
        'moExcelApplication.Quit()
        recordclear(moExcelApplication)

        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        'MessageBox.Show("Excel Closed")
        CloseExcelFile = bprocess

    End Try
End Function
Private Sub recordclear(ByVal o As Object)
    Try
        Do Until _
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) <= 0
        Loop
    Catch

    Finally
        o = Nothing
    End Try


End Sub


Public Function openExcel()
    Dim bprocess As Boolean
    Try
        moExcelApplication = New Excel.Application
        moWorkBooks = moExcelApplication.Workbooks

        If Not (moExcelApplication Is Nothing) Then
            If Not moWorkBooks Is Nothing Then
                moExcelWorkBook = moWorkBooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\anand\Desktop\amit2.xlsx")
                moExcelApplication.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Return bprocess

End Function


Public Function isOpen()
    On Error Resume Next
    moExcelWorkBook.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\anand\Desktop\amit2.xlsx")
    If Not moExcelWorkBook Is Nothing Then
        moExcelWorkBook.Nothing() = False
        On Error GoTo -1
        If moExcelWorkBook.ConnectionsDisabled = True Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    Else 'It is open
        moExcelWorkBook = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
        Return 1
    End If

End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

jst Check it out this work properly

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
    Private moExcelApplication As Excel.Application
    Private moExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Private moWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Private moActivesheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Private moWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets
    Private moCurrentRange As Excel.Range

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowDirect.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE")
End Sub

Private Sub Showobj_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Showobj.Click
    Dim sCount As String

    Try
        Cancel.Enabled = True
        If isopen() = 1 Then
            Call OpenExcelFile()
            moActivesheet = moExcelWorkBook.ActiveSheet
            moCurrentRange = moActivesheet.Range("a1", "e5")
            For i As Integer = 1 To 5
                For j As Integer = 1 To 5
                    sCount = i.ToString + j.ToString
                    moActivesheet.Cells(i, j).value = sCount
                Next
            Next
        Else

            MsgBox("already open")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
Private Declare Auto Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
          ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer


Private Sub Cancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
    'Dim oclass As Collection
    'Try
    '    Showobj.Enabled = True
    '    oclass = New Collection
    '    oclass.moExcelApplication = moExcelApplication
    '    oclass.moExcelWorkBook = moExcelWorkBook
    '    oclass.moCurrentRange = moCurrentRange
    '    oclass.CloseExcelFile()


    'Catch ex As Exception

    'End Try

    Try
        If (Not moExcelWorkBook Is Nothing) Then
            If (Not moExcelApplication Is Nothing) Then
                moExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
                moExcelWorkBook.Nothing() = True

            End If
        End If

        If (Not moExcelApplication Is Nothing) Then
            moExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = True
            moExcelWorkBook.Nothing() = True

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

        If moExcelApplication.Visible = True Then
            moExcelWorkBook.Close(False)
        Else
            MsgBox("Excel already closed")
        End If
        recordclear(moCurrentRange)
        recordclear(moActivesheet)
        recordclear(moWorkSheets)
        recordclear(moExcelWorkBook)
        recordclear(moWorkBooks)
        moExcelApplication.Quit()
        recordclear(moExcelApplication)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        MessageBox.Show("Excel Closed")
        Cancel.Enabled = False
    End Try



End Sub




Private Sub OpenExcelFile()
    Try
        moExcelApplication = New Excel.Application
        moWorkBooks = moExcelApplication.Workbooks

        If Not (moExcelApplication Is Nothing) Then
            If Not moWorkBooks Is Nothing Then
                moExcelWorkBook = moWorkBooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\anand\Desktop\amit2.xlsx")
                moExcelApplication.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
Function isopen()

    On Error Resume Next
    moExcelWorkBook.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\anand\Desktop\amit2.xlsx")
    If Not moExcelWorkBook Is Nothing Then
        moExcelWorkBook.Nothing() = False
        On Error GoTo -1
        If moExcelWorkBook.ConnectionsDisabled = True Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    Else 'It is open
        moExcelWorkBook = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
        Return 1
    End If

End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Showobj.Enabled = True
    Cancel.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub recordclear(ByVal o As Object)
    Try
        Do Until _
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) <= 0
        Loop
    Catch

    Finally
        o = Nothing
    End Try


End Sub
```

End Class